# Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'api.binance.com'

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, https, error-handling

I keep on getting this error the moment I enabled error messaging in Django. I research about it. This binance thingy is about bitcoin and it is not related to what I'm doing.
Is this an attack that's trying to check/access my Django Web app?

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'api.binance.com'. You may need to add 'api.binance.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Report at /api/v1/time
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'api.binance.com'. You may need to add 'api.binance.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Request Method: GET
```

I check the api.binance.com. It is like an api and it says "ok"
What's your thought about this?

Answer (score 0):

This is issue just means that external device on the internet is trying to connect on Django however since the the URL " api.binance.com" is not on the allowed list on Django settings.

It is giving error only when you enable the debugging to sent on your email.